# Question regarding proof that multiplication of equivalence classes of paths is associative.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, fundamental-groups

[image]

How do you show that $F$ as defined above is continuous? I do understand intuitively why $F$ is defined the way it is and I can understand intuitively why $F$ is continuous. But I'm not sure how you would actually prove that this function is continuous.

The best I can do is prove that if you fix $s \in [0,1]$, then the restriction of $F$ to the set $I \times\{s\}$ is continuous. I thought about then using the Glue lemma to glue all of these "horizontal strips" together, but there are infinitely many and they are all closed but not open subsets of $I\times I$, and the glue lemma only works for finite unions of closed sets.

I've looked at other sources, and they all give this function $F$ (or something similar at least). But no source actually proves that $F$ is continuous. Am I missing something obvious as to how you can easily show that this function is continuous?

EDIT: Sorry, just to add, the source of the above text is "A basic course in topology" by William S. Massey

Comment: It's clearly continuous everywhere besides the points where $t\in\left\{\frac{s+1}4,\frac{s+2}4\right\}$ since the composition of continuous functions is continuous. So you just need to show it's continuous at those points as well.

Comment: Apologies, this is exactly the issue I'm struggling with. I understand why the function is continuous like you've said, but I don't know how to write a formal proof of that fact.

Comment: The key tool to use is the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).

Comment: @Lee do I need to use the glue/pasting lemma in a different way to what I've mentioned in my OP?

Comment: In the $st$-plane, the lines $t = (s+1)/4$ and $t=(s+2)/4$ divide the rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ into 3 pieces.  Use the pasting lemma on those three pieces.